# CloudKit Entitlement missing

Tags: swift, xcode, cloudkit, xcode11

I wanted to implement CloudKit into my application, however I can't add it into my project.

Most tutorials were made in an older Xcode version (I assume) where they had a switch for iCloud - In my project (Xcode 11) this is not the case. The Capabilities Tab looks like this for me:
[image: Xcode Screenshot]

As you can see there is no iCloud or CloudKit option.
I can import CloudKit in the code, but I get the runtime error 'The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services' I assume this is because I didn't add it to capabilities.

Note that I did create the project with CloudKit enabled:
[image: Xcode Project creation]

Does anyone know where I can add the entitlement to the project? Or how else I can include CloudKit into my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capabilities available to an iOS app depend on your program membership.

iCloud is only available to paid members of the Apple Developer Program.

The free tier of Apple Developer only has access to following capabilities (which are the one's you have shown as available):

- App Groups
- Background Modes
- Data Protection
- HealthKit
- HomeKit
- Inter-App Audio
- Keychain Sharing
- Maps
- Wireless Accessory Configuration

I've attached a link which shows the full list supported capabilities for each membership level.

[Supported Capabilities for Membership levels](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6)